# Redirect SubDomain Request to a Specific Port

Tags: sharepoint, iis, subdomain

I have a SharePoint solution running, with different applications running on different ports. Now I have to assign 3 subdomains to 3 different applications like:
sub1.domain.com on port 36358
sub2.domain.com on port 36359
sub3.domain.com on port 36360
My network admin says that dns setting goes as long as server address, not a specific port. Now, can I set my SharePoint IIS so that requests for different subdomains go to their related ports?

Comment: Better asked on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setup the host headers for the specific Web Sites.

From IIs manager:

< Your Web Site >->Properties->Web Site->Web site identification->Advanced

Also, you will need to add your full domain name in the "Define managed paths" in WSS Central Admin.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for the reply.
So I don't need to set all the port numbers to 80?